# images overlapping with masonry on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, masonry

i am trying to use masonry for a gallery on rails. right now this is my html:

---

```
<div id = "grid" class = "transitions-enabled">
<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag"https://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9aqegpJ4j1rzugjbo1_r1_500.png" %></div>

<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag "http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5wb2lom6X1rz6b7fo1_500.jpg" %></div>

<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag "https://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9as7bOSXt1rzugjbo1_500.png" %></div>

<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag "http://36.media.tumblr.com/886f9d69a50a45330bd5c6c958eeed72/tumblr_ngnn3tUjJs1tpjk9no1_400.png"%></div>

<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fc/f7/f4/fcf7f4416b58634117766e5e705d1ef6.jpg" %></div>

<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag "http://fanaru.com/spongebob-squarepants/image/8392-spongebob-squarepants-tea-at-the-treedome-episode-screencap-1x3.jpg" %></div>

<div class="grid-item"><%= image_tag "http://www.barnorama.com/wp-content/images/2013/01/Times-Spongebob-Made-Absolutely/01-Times-Spongebob-Made-Absolutely.jpg" %>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my css in my home.scss file:

```
.grid-item { 
width: 120px;
}
```

this is my javascript file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var $grid = $('#grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});

  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});


});
```

right now my images are overlapping. how do i get them to not overlap?

Answer (score 0):

That's because masonry does the magic by setting the position of each image by their sizes. But before images are loaded, it doesn't know what the sizes are so it just use the img tag's size.

You need to use the `imagesLoaded` function, and call masonry in the callback, which will tell masonry to calculate the position after images are loaded.

In your case, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $gridItem = $('.grid-item');
  $gridItem.hide(); // this will hide the images until they are loaded
  var $grid = $('#grid').imageLoaded(function() {
    $gridItem.fadeIn();  // you don't need this if you didn't hide them in the first place.
    $grid.masonry({
      ... // your properties here
    });
  });
```